# Magento 2 REST API understanding fields

Tags: api, rest, magento2

Can someone explain the "status" and "visibility" fields on each product in the list obtained through Magento 2 REST API?

When calling the /products endpoint a list of products are returned but I'm having issues understanding the different fields. Sure, some fields are self explanatory like sku, name, etc. but others like status and visibility aren't.

Looking at the documentation, I can see both values are integers but no further explanation as to what values are allowed and what they actually mean? That makes the documentation kinda useless since I can probably just guess the type looking at the often related GET-request.

Documentation found here:
https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.1-admin/tag/products#operation/catalogProductRepositoryV1GetListGet

I have no former experience with Magento :D

Maybe there is a reference list somewhere that explains each field?

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at four constants at the top of the class Visibility: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Visibility.php

```
const VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE = 1;
const VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG = 2;
const VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH = 3;
const VISIBILITY_BOTH = 4;
```

you will see what values are allowed and what they mean: IN_CATALOG means that the product will not be taken into account when user is using search, while IN_SEARCH means that the product will not show on product page and category page, but will be returned in search results, the other two (NOT_VISIBLE, BOTH) are a combination of these two both being false or both being true.
Now about status - have a look here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Source/Status.php
Again, you have constants which are used to store the status:

```
/**
 * Product Status values
 */
const STATUS_ENABLED = 1;
const STATUS_DISABLED = 2;
```

I hope this answers your question :)